# Best webcam to use with Skype and a Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini, skype, webcam

My users are requesting that we set up a conference room [Mac mini](http://www.apple.com/macmini/) (2009) for videochats using Skype.

Since iSights are no longer reliably available (and I'm not going to give up my personal one), has anyone tried any 3rd-party webcams to use under OS X, such as any of [Logitech's](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams)?  Any other brands you'd recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Most modern USB webcams support a generic interface called UVC (Universal Video Class). OSX supports most UVC drivers out-of-the-box (true for me in Snow Leopard) so sometimes there aren't even any third-party drivers to install. (In fact, most third-party webcam "drivers" only install useless add-ons that bloat your system.)

Logitech is very good at providing compliant UVC devices, so they're a good starting point.

I have a [Logitech C525](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/7794), and it works great at 720p with its built-in microphone, using both Skype and Facetime. No additional drivers required.. plug-and-play!

Older webcams that do not support UVC will require drivers of course. Furthermore, super-new UVC devices may require an extension that OSX doesn't yet handle, obviously drivers are inevitable.

If you want a list of UVC-supported devices, see the [Linux UVC page](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices). (Yes, I know Linux != OSX, but this list can be used as a starting point of other brands you can try.)

Answer (score 1):

Another choice which works nicely with OS X is the [Logitech c910](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/webcam-communications/webcams/devices/hd-pro-webcam-c910).

in order to have 720p work, as well as a fast connection, you need a relatively fast computer. For example, 720 didn't work on my first gen Macbook Air but does work on my new 11 inch model.

Answer (score 1):

I've just bought a [Logitech C310](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c310) and it works perfectly on a 2014 Mac Mini running Yosemite. It cost about £25. I just plugged it in and made a video Skype call immediately. The video and sound quality are excellent. Please note - Logitech doesn't mention that it works on Mac. It does :)